# Integrating around simple pole and semicircle

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ with **simple** pole at $z_0$. Then if $\Gamma$ is a circle around $z_0$ oriented counter-clockwise with radius $r$ and $r\rightarrow 0$, then

$$\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz=2\pi i  Res_{z_0}(f)$$

That's a result from Residue Theorem. But I wonder why if we define $\Gamma'$ as the top semicircle of circle $\Gamma$ then

$$\int_{\Gamma'}f(z)dz=\pi i  Res_{z_0}(f)$$

It's quite counterintuitive to me because $f(z)$ need not to be symmetric etc. And why this only works when $z_0$ is a simple pole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your post, you talk about enclosing the pole $z_0$ in a circle. Then by the Residue Theorem, that is the $2\pi i\sum\text{Res}$. If there is no pole enclosed in the contour, the integral is zero.

When you speak of the upper semicircle, are you speaking of two halves a circle still enclosing the pole? If so, the pole is still enclosed in the contour. If you are talking about this contour, 
[image]

We will pick up only half the residue. Don't mind the placement of the pole since it could have been else where. This was already pre-LaTeXed up on my computer. The integral then would be
$$
\int_Cf(z)dz = \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{-R}^{\epsilon}f(z)dz - \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{\epsilon}^{R}f(z)dz = 0
$$
which equals zero since there is no pole in the contour. We would have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz
$$
where $\gamma$ is the small semicirle. Additionally, we pick the $-\int_{\gamma}$ since the integration is clockwise instead of counter clockwise. By the Jordan Lemma, $\int_{\Gamma}\to 0$ as $R\to\infty$. Now, let $f(z) = a/z + h(z)$ where $h$ is holomorphic at the $z_0$. Then the integral over $h$ goes to zero as $\epsilon\to 0$. Let $z = \epsilon e^{i\theta}$ so $dz = \epsilon ie^{i\theta}d\theta$. The integral over $a/z$ is now
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{a}{z}dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{a\epsilon ie^{i\theta}}{\epsilon e^{i\theta}}d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}ai \ d\theta = \pi i a
$$
For $z_0$ not simple, we have 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{a}{z^n}dz.
$$
where $n\geq 2$.
Again, let $z=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ so $dz$ is the same.
$$
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ai\epsilon}{\epsilon^ne^{i(n-1)\theta}}d\theta = \infty
$$
for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Probably the most common example found in Complex Analysis books is to calculuate
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}dz.
$$

Comment: ill award bounty once i can, in 22 hours

Comment: I was mostly asking about that small semicircle around the pole. I wondered why we can just take half of the residue even if $f$ isnt symmetric. If you know what I mean.

Comment: For example if we have integral $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$, then USUALLY, it is $\ne \frac{1}{2} \int_0^2 f(x)dx$

Comment: Yes, I see now, thanks

Comment: If we enclose a pole, we have a full revolution around it so the winding number is one and we have $1\cdot 2\pi i$.

Comment: But we take integral over upper semicircle, and I just wasnt sure why we can jsut mutiply integral over whole circle by $1/2$ to get it

Comment: @luka5z you see $\gamma$ the small semicirle. We can write that integral as $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{a}{z}dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{a}{z}dz.$$ I chose the later to emphasize the 1/2 of residue.

Comment: I understand it now! Perfect! Thanks

Comment: Added bounty, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $z_0=0$ and that $f(z) = \alpha/z + g(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic around $0$. In particular $g$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$ so that
$$ \int_{\Gamma'}f(z){\rm d}z = \alpha\int_{\Gamma'}\frac{{\rm d}z}{z} + O(r) = \pi i \alpha + O(r).$$
So that *in the limit $r\to0$*, we have the equality you stated.

When there is a double pole, the situation is different because then $\int_{\Gamma'}{\rm d}z/z^2$ tends to infinity (roughly like $1/r$). In short, $f$ itself being symmetric doesn't play a role because all that matters when you take the limit as $r\to0$ is the pole contribution, which has symmetry.