# Contour integration with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1-\cos(2z)}{z^2(z^2+1)}}\, dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1-\cos(2z)}{z^2(z^2+1)}}\, dz$$

The contour is shaped like this (image from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1128114/995613)) [image: Contour image]

With $\epsilon$ being the radius of the smaller semi-circle. The integral over that part specifically is :

$$\begin{align}\int_{\gamma}{f(z)\, dz}&=\int_{\pi}^{0}{\frac{1-e^{2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{(\epsilon e^{i\theta})^2((\epsilon e^{i\theta})^2+1)}i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\, d\theta}\\&=-i\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{1-e^{2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{\epsilon^3e^{3i\theta}+\epsilon e^{i\theta}}\, d\theta}\\&\leq\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{|1-e^{2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}|}{|\epsilon^3e^{3i\theta}+\epsilon e^{i\theta}|}\, d\theta}\\&=\frac{1}{|\epsilon^3-\epsilon|}\int_{0}^{\pi}{|1-e^{2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}|\, d\theta}\end{align}$$

I'm  not sure how to bound this though. In the end $\epsilon\to0$, but I'm not sure if that can be used yet. Any hints?

Comment: As $\epsilon\to0^+$, the integral along the small arc approaches a finite but nonzero value; it's the limit, not a bound, that you need. Alternative technique: if you instead take the real part of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1+2iz-e^{2iz}}{z^2(z^2+1)}$, $z=0$ is a removable singularity instead of a pole, so you can take a simple semicircular contour rather than one that avoids $z=0$.

Comment: @J.G. I didn't expect it to be non-zero. To use the fact it's a removable singularity would I need to expand the $e^{2iz}$ term in that integral as a series or something like that?

Comment: (i) If $f(\epsilon)\to L$ you want to bound $f-L$, not $f$. (ii) Yes, using the series for $e^{2iz} would do.

Comment: If you take such a detour around a *pole*, always expect it to be finite. When you take a detour around a branch point or a removable singularity is when you would expect it to be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z) = \displaystyle\frac{1-\exp\left(2iz\right)}{z^{2}\left(1+z^{2}\right)}$. As $\epsilon \to 0$, here are two ways to evaluate the contour integral over $\gamma$:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\gamma} f(z)dz &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\pi}^{0}f\left(\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)d\left(\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right) \\
&= \int_{\pi}^{0}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1-\exp\left(2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)}{\epsilon^{2}e^{2i\theta}\left(1+\epsilon^{2}e^{2i\theta}\right)}\cdot\epsilon ie^{i\theta}d\theta \\
&= i\int_{\pi}^{0}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\left(1-\exp\left(2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)\right)}{\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\epsilon e^{i\theta}\left(1+\epsilon^{2}e^{2i\theta}\right)}d\theta \\
&= i\int_{\pi}^{0}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{-\exp\left(2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\right)\cdot2ie^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}+3\epsilon^{2}e^{3i\theta}}d\theta \\
&= i\int_{\pi}^{0}(-2i)d\theta \\
&= -2\pi
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\gamma} f(z)dz &= -i\pi \operatorname{Res}(f(z), z=0) \\
&= -i\pi\frac{1}{\left(2-1\right)!}\lim_{z\to0}\frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}\left(z-0\right)^{2}\frac{1-\exp\left(2iz\right)}{z^{2}\left(1+z^{2}\right)} \\
&= -i\pi \lim_{z\to0}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1-\exp\left(2iz\right)}{1+z^{2}} \\
&= -i\pi \lim_{z\to0}\frac{-2z+2e^{2iz}\left(-iz^{2}+z-i\right)}{\left(1+z^{2}\right)^{2}} \\
&= -i\pi\left(-2i\right) \\
&= -2\pi.
\end{align}
$$

From here, I'm sure you will be able to prove that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos\left(2x\right)}{x^{2}\left(x^{2}+1\right)}dx = \pi+\frac{\pi}{e^{2}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for the 2nd equality on the first section, can you swap the limit and integral because you already know it converges?

Comment: Afaik you can just apply DCT @AnthonyML

Comment: @AnthonyML I think the answer is yes. I'll admit it feels "cheesy" for me to switch the limit and integral signs, especially since I didn't prove that the limit is justified by uniform convergence. Swapping the limit and integral signs should be valid for this answer by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the pole $z=0$, we  split the integral into two as $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos 2z}{z^2\left(z^2+1\right)} d z  =& 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 z}{z^2\left(z^2+1\right)} d z \\
= & 2  \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 z}{z^2} d z}_{=\pi} -\underbrace{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2  \sin ^2 z}{z^2+1} d z}_{J} 
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
J & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos 2 z}{z^2+1} d z \\
& = \underbrace{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^2+1} d z}_{=\pi} -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2 z}{z^2+1} d z
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can use contour integration along $\gamma$, the upper semi-circle in anti-clockwise direction, to evaluate the last integral.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2 z}{z^2+1} d z & =\operatorname{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2 z i}}{z^2+1} d z \\
& =\operatorname{Re}\left(2 \pi i \oint_\gamma \frac{e^{2 z i}}{z^2+1} d z\right) \\
& =\operatorname{Re}\left[2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{2 z^2}}{z^2+1}, i\right)\right] \\
& =\operatorname{Re}\left(2 \pi i \cdot \frac{e^{-2}}{2 i}\right)=\pi e^{-2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence we can conclude that
$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos 2z}{z^2\left(z^2+1\right)} d z  =\pi\left(1+e^{-2}\right) }$$